# Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Hartl) Chapter 7.2.3 RSpec test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working my through Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I have gotten up to chapter 7, but one of my RSpec test cases is failing, specifically the one dealing with passwords that do not match:

```
describe "has_password? method" do

    it "should be true if the passwords match" do
        @user.has_password?(@attr[:password]).should be_true
    end

    it "should be false if the passwords don't match" do
        @user.has_password?("invalid").should be_false
    end
end
```

Output from Terminal:
Failures:

```
  1) User password encryption has_password? method should be false if the passwords don't match
 Failure/Error: @user.has_password?("invalid").should be_false
   expected "273725daa81e74764ea1e941a0789da7d580656cd321c64e39d1389f6a7e14d9" to be false
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:111
```

Here is my `/user.rb` code:

```
require 'digest'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :password
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :name,  :presence => true,
                  :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
validates :email, :presence => true,
                  :format   => { :with => email_regex },
                  :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

validates :password, :presence     => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length       => { :within => 6..40}


before_save :encrypt_password

def has_password? (submitted_password)
    encrypted_password = encrypt(submitted_password)

end

private 

    def encrypt_password
        self.salt = make_salt unless has_password? (password)
        self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
        secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
        secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
        Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end


end
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong for the life of me. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `has_password?` method

`encrypted_password = encrypt(submitted_password)` needs to read:
`encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)`

Comment: You just beat me to the answer :-)

Comment: Oh wow. I guess that's what I get for not reading character by character! Thanks!